# ,necesito ayuda con un metodo que me pide lo siguiente, retornar todos los pacientes menores a 13 años, el problema es que no se como plantearlo

Tags: java

```
public static Paciente[] pacientesPediatricos(Paciente[] pacienteArray){

    for(int i=0;i<pacienteArray.length;i++){
        Paciente paciente = pacienteArray[i];
        if(paciente.getEdad() <= 13){
            pacienteArray[i] = paciente;
        }
        System.out.println("son " + pacienteArray);
    }
    return pacienteArray;
}
```

Desde ya gracias, espero que alguien sepa sacarme las dudas de esto

Comment: Deberías darte una vuelta por [ask] y de paso hacer el [tour], tu pregunta no se entiende, de paso edita y agrega el código como texto y evita redactar en mayúsculas sostenidas

Comment: funciona lo que tienes si o no?, tienes el resultado esperado si o no ?, emite algún error? cual. esta son las cosas que debes auto preguntarte antes de preguntar haca y obviamente colocar el código en formato de texto no imágenes.

Comment: [Te podrían votar negativamente porque una captura del código no es aceptable](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/), publica el texto del código como tal. Dado que el código "no te está funcionando", incluye el comportamiento erróneo o los mensajes de error que estás obteniendo. Para más información lee [ask]. Un saludo.

Comment: por favor saquen los votos negativos y si me hice todas esas preguntas por que crees que estoy aca , se ve que ustedes no se equivocan nunca es la primera vez que uso esta pagina no se bien como funciona estuve intentando muchas veces poner codigo y salia error de formato y bueno recurria una imagen  . pero porfavor entiendan y no voten negativo pq de verdad necesito la ayuda

Answer (score 1):

prueba con este código:

```
public static Paciente[] pacientesPediatricos(Paciente[] pacientes) {
    List<Paciente> pacientesPediatricos = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < pacientes.length; i++) {
        Paciente paciente = pacientes[i];
        if (paciente.getEdad() <= 13) {
            pacientesPediatricos.add(paciente);
        }
    }
    return pacientesPediatricos.toArray(new Paciente[pacientesPediatricos.size()]);
}
```

El problema que veo es que tomas el valor de `pacientaArray[i]`, miras su edad y lo vuelves a asignar a `pacienteArry[i]`con lo que no obtienes el subconjunto de resultados que buscas. Tienes que crear un nuevo array donde almacenar solo los pediátricos.
Dado que no sabes el número de pacientes <= 13 años se hace difícil trabajar con arrays. Te recomiendo el uso de `List<Paciente>` que siempre es más versátil que los arrays.

Comment: hola gracias por comentar me sirve la ayuda , lo voy a probar .  no se bien como usar esta pagina y no puse todo el ejercicio ... el tema es que ya tengo un array en clase main donde tengo creados todos los objetos de tipo paciente ... solo que no se como hacer para que retorne lo que me pide , pregunte al profesor de la universidad y me dijo que cree un array donde los pacientes que cumplan la condicion los guarde ahi pero sigo sin captarlo.. otra vez me disculpo por poner todo el ejercicio y gracias por responder